# Failed to sync db: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dpg-ch8us7tgk4qeoo05re10-a

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I keep getting this issue when trying to connect to my postgresql db from my node application, below is my database.js file

```
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  database: "open_fabric",
  host: process.env.DB_PROD_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_PROD_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PROD_PASS,
  url: process.env.DB_PROD_URL,
  dialect: "postgres",
};
```

and below is my index.js

```
const dbConfig = require("../db/database");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  dbConfig.database,
  dbConfig.username,
  dbConfig.password,
  dbConfig
);
const db = {};
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.user = require("./user.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.product = require("./product.model")(sequelize, Sequelize);

console.log(dbConfig);

module.exports = db;
```

Suggestions??

I tried troubleshooting with my database.js and trying other credentials, nothing seemed to be working.

Comment: what version of postgres and nodejs are you using?